# Show datapoint as a table disappear when I add a line to the chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using line and clustered column chart.

Before adding the line I'm able to show datapoint as a table:

[image]

When I add a line to the chart (measure) the same feature is disabled:

[image]

How come?